# Delphi - конвертировать GIF в PNG

Tags: delphi, png, изображения, конвертер

Есть ли возможность без лишних библиотек средствами Delphi конвертировать картинку GIF в PNG?
Хотелось бы поиметь пример.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, целиком это не возможно, т.к. GIF это несколько изображений идущих, друг-за-другом, по кругу. 
В новых версия делфи есть классы TGIFImage и TPNGImage.
Открываете GIF, переходите на нужный фрейм, методом aasign получаете Bitmap фрейма в TPNgImage и сохраняете в PNG.

Для старых придется искать лишние библиотеки.

Вот пример, где я вынимаю первый фрейм из GIF'а и сохраняю в PNG:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
  Vcl.Graphics;

var
  gif: TGIFImage;
  png: TPngImage;
  bmp: TBitmap;

begin
  gif := TGIFImage.Create;
  png := TPngImage.Create;
  gif.LoadFromFile('c:\mygif1.gif');
  bmp := gif.Images.Frames[0].Bitmap;
  png.Assign(bmp);
  png.SaveToFile('c:\mygif1.png');
```

Comment: На самом деле в gif одна картинка. У меня Delphi XE3.

Comment: TGIFImage нашёл в модуле Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg

Comment: смотрите пример, как вынимать фрейм из GIF контейнера.

Comment: а если там только один фрем, так не получится?
Var
 GIFImage: TGIFImage;
 PNGImage: TPNGImage;
begin
...
...
    GIFImage.LoadFromStream(gif);
    PNGImage.Assign(GIFImage);
    PNGImage.SaveToStream(png);

Comment: При удалении BMP получаю AV invalid pointer operation

procedure GifToPNG(gif, png: TMemoryStream);
Var
 GIFImage:TGIFImage;
 PNGImage:TPNGImage;
 BMPImage:TBitmap;
begin
  if (not assigned(gif)) and (not assigned(png)) then exit;

  GIFImage:=TGIFImage.Create;
  PNGImage:=TPNGImage.Create;
  BMPImage:=TBitmap.Create;
  try
    GIFImage.LoadFromStream(gif);
    BMPImage:=GIFImage.Images.Frames[0].Bitmap;
    PNGImage.Assign(BMPImage);
    PNGImage.SaveToStream(png);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(GIFImage);
    FreeAndNil(PNGImage);
    FreeAndNil(BMPImage);AV invalid pointer operation
  end;
end;

Comment: нет, не получиться. GIF это контейнер. Даже если там 1 изображение, оно все равно записано как 1й кадр.